# Jobtracker UI not working properly on osx

Tags: macos, user-interface, hadoop, homebrew

Hadoop itself (i.e hdfs and map/reduce) **is** working - and brew-installed hive as well  (which validates the first two). Just the GUI is weird: see the attached screenshot: the webserver is up but the JobTracker is not providing any useful info

**jobtracker.jsp not found:**

[image]

**Anyone home at all on port 50030 (yes!)**

[image]

**What about namenode ui?**

[image]

Comment: This is not limited to osx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error on hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.5.0 installation. After spending some time looking into the code, I managed to get this working by applying following patch to hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.5.0.jar:

```
diff --git a/org/apache/hadoop/http/HttpServer.java b/org/apache/hadoop/http/HttpServer.java
index 25b4c75..1896623 100644
--- a/org/apache/hadoop/http/HttpServer.java
+++ b/org/apache/hadoop/http/HttpServer.java
@@ -237,6 +237,10 @@ public class HttpServer implements FilterContainer {
     webAppContext.setDisplayName(name);
     webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
     webAppContext.setWar(appDir + "/" + name);
+
+    webAppContext.setDescriptor(appDir + "/" + name + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
+    webAppContext.setResourceBase(appDir + "/" + name);
+
     webAppContext.getServletContext().setAttribute(CONF_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, conf);
     webAppContext.getServletContext().setAttribute(ADMINS_ACL, adminsAcl);
     addNoCacheFilter(webAppContext);
```

basically the jobtracker/tasktracker webapp initialization using Jetty WebAppContext was missing the web.xml location, adding it there using setDescriptor() and setting resourceBase correctly using setResourceBase() solves the problem.

Comment: Wow. Is there a hadoop JIRA for this?

Comment: I am going to accept this. Please consider (a) putting a JIRA / pull request for this, and (b) upvoting.